# Oracle R2DBC URL for Oracle Autonomous Database

Tags: oracle, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

Newbie question: Getting invalid URL error. What is the url that I need to configure in application.xml for Oracle Autonomous Database with r2dbc? Is Oracle Autonomous Database even supported to be used with r2dbc?

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.r2dbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>oracle-r2dbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

application.xml

```
spring:
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:oracle@dbname_tp?TNS_ADMIN=/Users/johndoe/development/Wallet_dbname
    username: dbusername
    password: dbpassword
```

Error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: r2dbc:oracle@dbname_tp?TNS_ADMIN=/Users/johndoe/development/Wallet_dbname
at io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionUrlParser.validate(ConnectionUrlParser.java:67) ~[r2dbc-spi-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]